# Embedding require.js in optimized script

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs

RequireJS has a nice feature to optimize a JS project into one single script (let's call it `foo.js`).

If I include `foo.js`, I get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`. The error goes away if I add `require.js` before `foo.js`, because `define` is defined by RequireJS. I don't want my library users to have to do that to use it.

Can I make RequireJS embed itself inside the `foo.js` in a proper way? Would concatenating files be acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, the maintainer of RequireJS has put out a project just for that, [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond).

I haven't used it, but from the description:

> "Some developers like to use the AMD API to code modular JavaScript, but after doing an optimized build, they do not want to include a full AMD loader like RequireJS, since they do not need all that functionality.  [...]  By including almond in the built file, there is no need for RequireJS. "

Comment: I had never heard of it. Sounds like the perfect solution.